# How to add children to existing Angular Mat-Tree nodes

Tags: angular, angular-material, treeview

I am creating an Angular Mat-tree to show the directory structure of my file system.
I can get a list of all root folders and show them in Mat-tree using the official example from the following link [example](https://material.angular.io/components/tree/examples)

But how can I add child items to the existing parent nodes and then add another level by adding new data as the user expands the items?

I Currently have this

```
  treeControl = new FlatTreeControl<DirectoryItemFlatNode>(
    node => node.level,
    node => node.expandable,
  );

  treeFlattener = new MatTreeFlattener(
    this._transformer,
    node => node.level,
    node => node.expandable,
    node => node.children,
  );

  dataSource = new MatTreeFlatDataSource(this.treeControl, this.treeFlattener);

this.dataSource.data = TREE_DATA;
```